# Trying to increase resolution of ADC using an op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, adc, instrumentation-amplifier

We currently have a circuit measuring a thermistor in a water tank, passing through a couple of voltage dividers and then plugging into an 12bit ADC which eventually interacts with a microcontroller and solenoid to help regulate a cooler for the water tank temperature.

The problem is that while currently our 12bit ADC operates between 0-5V, the temperature of the thermistor is only fluctuating between 8k-12k (between 20-30degC.) This means we are only really using 1.3-1.6V of the range of our ADC, and missing out on a ton of potential resolution.

I was hoping we could figure out how take that .3V difference in our current range, and using something like an op-amp to magnify it and have a range between 1-4V, but so far I have only been able to increase the resolution by 2-3x or so that way.

Am I way off track here?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying for?  Still have a lot to learn and could use some insight.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you would like to mention how exactly you have tried to use the op-amp to increase range? Draw a schematic.

Comment: Many ADC allow you to change its DC REFERENCE voltage (within reasonable limits). Can you set this reference voltage lower than +5V?

Comment: You're throwing away almost a bit of resolution with that divider. Do  you not have any requirement to read the approximate temperature outside of a narrow range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This difference amp circuit should do the trick for you:
[image: op amp circuit]
I have simulated the thermistor R4 to vary over time from 8k to 12k ohms.

The resistor R1, R3, and R5 were chosen to match the center of the thermistor range. This sets the common mode voltage to 2.5 volts, and amplifies the differential voltage caused by the thermistor varying with gain set by R2, I used 33k.

[image: graph of output and thermistor]
The blue trace is the resistance of the thermistor using the right axis. The black trace is the voltage going to the ADC.

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly the type of solution that I knew was there but was eluding me.  Very instructive, appreciate it!